# How to make trailing motion effect on CustomView

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ontouchlistener

I created a CustomView to paint. When we touch the view I will mark the point to bitmap and draw it in next cycle.

This was worked for me perfectly. And I want to make a trailing effect while we moving the pointer. That means while we moving the pointer view should mark the point and eventually it will fade out( in 2 seconds).

My problem was I can't change the paint on each point.

I am very noob to CustomView.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

```
package com.godwin.handdrawview;

import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PathMeasure;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.Xfermode;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.DrawableRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.graphics.ColorUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;

import com.godwin.handdrawview.view.ViewCompat;
import com.godwin.handdrawview.view.ViewTreeObserverCompat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Godwin on 13-11-2017 15:21 for DrawView.
 *
 * @author : Godwin Joseph Kurinjikattu
 */
public class HandDrawView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = HandDrawView.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH = 10;
    private static final int DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH_FOR_ERASER = 50;
    private static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private TimePoint mPoint;

    private static final int DOUBLE_CLICK_DELAY_MS = 200;
    private boolean mClearOnDoubleClick;
    private long mFirstClick;
    private int mCountClick;

    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mDummyPaint;

    private RectF mDirtyRect;

    private int mStrokeWidth = DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH;
    private int mStrokeWidthForEraser = DEFAULT_STROKE_WIDTH_FOR_ERASER;

    private int mStrokeColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;

    @DrawableRes
    private int mPointerRes = 0;

    private Bitmap mPointerBitmap = null;
    private Bitmap mOverlayBitmap = null;
    private Bitmap mDrawingBitmap = null;
    private Canvas mDrawingBitmapCanvas = null;

    private List<TimePoint> mPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<TimePoint> mPointsCache = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<TimePoint> mExtractedPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<TimePoint> mFadeTimePoints = new ArrayList<>();

    private ControlTimedPoints mControlPointCached = null;
    private Bezier mBezierCached = new Bezier();

    private OnDrawListener mOnDrawListener;

    private boolean isCapturing;
    private boolean isFadeEffect;

    private PathMeasure mPathMeasure;
    private Path mPath;

    private Mode mMode = Mode.MARKER;

    /**
     * Simple constructor to use when creating a view from code.
     *
     * @param context The Context the view is running in, through which it can                access the current theme, resources, etc.
     */
    public HandDrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Hand draw view.
     *
     * @param context the context
     * @param attrs   the attrs
     */
    public HandDrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Hand draw view.
     *
     * @param context      the context
     * @param attrs        the attrs
     * @param defStyleAttr the def style attr
     */
    public HandDrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Hand draw view.
     *
     * @param context      the context
     * @param attrs        the attrs
     * @param defStyleAttr the def style attr
     * @param defStyleRes  the def style res
     */
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public HandDrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

        Bundle state = new Bundle();
        state.putParcelable("PARENT", superState);
        state.putInt("mStrokeWidth", mStrokeWidth);
        state.putInt("mStrokeColor", mStrokeColor);
        state.putInt("mPointerRes", mPointerRes);

        return state;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        Bundle savedState = (Bundle) state;

        Parcelable superState = savedState.getParcelable("PARENT");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(superState);

        mStrokeColor = savedState.getInt("mStrokeColor");
        mStrokeWidth = savedState.getInt("mStrokeWidth");
        mPointerRes = savedState.getInt("mPointerRes");

        initPaint();
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int defStyleRes) {
        final TypedArray attrArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.HandDrawView, defStyle, defStyleRes);
        initAttributes(attrArray);

        mDirtyRect = new RectF();
        initPaint();
        initPath();
//        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }

    private void initPaint() {
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
        mPaint.setColor(mStrokeColor);

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

        mDummyPaint = new Paint();
    }

    private void initPath() {
        mPathMeasure = new PathMeasure();
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    private void initAttributes(TypedArray attrArray) {
        this.mStrokeColor = attrArray.getInt(R.styleable.HandDrawView_strokeColor, mStrokeColor);
        this.mStrokeWidth = attrArray.getInt(R.styleable.HandDrawView_strokeWidth, mStrokeWidth);
        this.mPointerRes = attrArray.getInt(R.styleable.HandDrawView_pointerDrawable, mPointerRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mDrawingBitmap != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mDrawingBitmap, 0, 0, getPaint());
        }
        if (mPointerBitmap != null && mPoint != null) {
            drawPointerBitmap(canvas, mPoint);
        } else if (mPointerBitmap == null && mPoint != null) {
            drawCustomPointer(canvas, mPoint);
        }
        if (mOverlayBitmap != null) {
            drawOverlayBitmap(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void drawCustomPointer(Canvas canvas, TimePoint mPoint) {
        float x = mPoint.getX(), y = mPoint.getY();
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        path.lineTo(x + 10, y);
        path.lineTo(x + 100, y - 100);
        path.lineTo(x + 120, y - 110);
        path.lineTo(x + 90, y - 130);
        path.lineTo(x + 70, y - 90);
        path.lineTo(x, y - 10);
        path.lineTo(x, y);

        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);

    }

    private void drawPointerBitmap(Canvas canvas, TimePoint point) {
        if (mPointerBitmap != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mPointerBitmap,
                    point.getX(),
                    point.getY() - mPointerBitmap.getHeight(),
                    mDummyPaint);
        }
    }

    private void drawOverlayBitmap(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mOverlayBitmap,
                getWidth() / 2 - mOverlayBitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                getHeight() / 2 - mOverlayBitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                mDummyPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled())
            return false;
        TimePoint p = TimePoint.from(event.getX(), event.getY());
        mPoint = p.clone();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                mPoints.clear();
                mFadeTimePoints.clear();

                if (isDoubleClick()) break;
                this.mLastTouchX = event.getX();
                this.mLastTouchY = event.getY();
                moveTo();
                addPoint(getNewPoint(p));
                if (null != mOnDrawListener) {
                    mOnDrawListener.onStartDraw(this);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                resetDirtyRect(p);
                lineTo();
                addPoint(getNewPoint(p));
                if (null != mOnDrawListener) {
                    mOnDrawListener.onDrawing(this, getBitmap());
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                resetDirtyRect(p);
                addPoint(getNewPoint(p));
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                if (null != mOnDrawListener) {
                    mOnDrawListener.onStopDrawing(this, getBitmap());
                }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        //invalidate();
        invalidate(
                (int) (mDirtyRect.left),
                (int) (mDirtyRect.top),
                (int) (mDirtyRect.right),
                (int) (mDirtyRect.bottom));
        return true;
    }

    private void moveTo() {
        mPath.moveTo(mPoint.x, mPoint.y);
    }

    private void lineTo() {
        mPath.lineTo(mPoint.x, mPoint.y);
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(TimePoint point) {
// The mLastTouchX and mLastTouchY were set when the ACTION_DOWN motion event occurred.
        mDirtyRect.left = Math.min(mLastTouchX, point.x);
        mDirtyRect.right = Math.max(mLastTouchX, point.x);
        mDirtyRect.top = Math.min(mLastTouchY, point.y);
        mDirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(mLastTouchY, point.y);
    }

    private void addPoint(TimePoint timePoint) {
        capture(timePoint);
        mPoints.add(timePoint);

        int pointsCount = mPoints.size();
        if (pointsCount > 3) {

            ControlTimedPoints tmp = calculateCurveControlPoints(mPoints.get(0), mPoints.get(1), mPoints.get(2));
            TimePoint t2 = tmp.t2;
            recyclePoint(tmp.t1);

            tmp = calculateCurveControlPoints(mPoints.get(1), mPoints.get(2), mPoints.get(3));
            TimePoint t3 = tmp.t1;
            recyclePoint(tmp.t2);

            Bezier curve = mBezierCached.set(mPoints.get(1), t2, t3, mPoints.get(2));
            addBezier(curve);

            // Remove the first element from the list,
            // so that we always have no more than 4 mPoints in mPoints array.
            recyclePoint(mPoints.remove(0));

            recyclePoint(t2);
            recyclePoint(t3);
        } else if (pointsCount == 1) {
            // To reduce the initial lag make it work with 3 mPoints
            // by duplicating the first point
            mPoints.add(getNewPoint(mPoints.get(0)));
        }
    }

    private void capture(TimePoint timePoint) {
        if (isCapturing)
            mExtractedPoints.add(timePoint.clone());
    }

    //region Setter and getter

    /**
     * Start capturing.
     */
    public void startCapturing() {
        this.isCapturing = true;
        mExtractedPoints.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Stop capaturing.
     */
    public void stopCapturing() {
        this.isCapturing = false;
    }

    /**
     * Is capturing boolean.
     *
     * @return the boolean
     */
    public boolean isCapturing() {
        return isCapturing;
    }

    public boolean isFadeEffect() {
        return isFadeEffect;
    }

    public void setFadeEffect(boolean fadeEffect) {
        isFadeEffect = fadeEffect;
    }

    /**
     * Gets stroke width.
     *
     * @return the stroke width
     */
    public int getStrokeWidth() {
        return mStrokeWidth;
    }

    /**
     * Sets stroke width.
     *
     * @param mStrokeWidth the m stroke width
     */
    public void setStrokeWidth(int mStrokeWidth) {
        this.mStrokeWidth = mStrokeWidth;
        ensureDrawingBitmap();
    }

    /**
     * Gets stroke width for eraser.
     *
     * @return the stroke width for eraser
     */
    public int getStrokeWidthForEraser() {
        return mStrokeWidthForEraser;
    }

    /**
     * Sets stroke width for eraser.
     *
     * @param mStrokeWidthForEraser the m stroke width for eraser
     */
    public void setStrokeWidthForEraser(int mStrokeWidthForEraser) {
        this.mStrokeWidthForEraser = mStrokeWidthForEraser;
    }

    /**
     * Gets stroke color.
     *
     * @return the stroke color
     */
    public int getStrokeColor() {
        return mStrokeColor;
    }

    /**
     * Sets stroke color.
     *
     * @param mStrokeColor the m stroke color
     */
    public void setStrokeColor(int mStrokeColor) {
        this.mStrokeColor = mStrokeColor;
        if (null == mPaint) {
            initPaint();
        } else {
            mPaint.setColor(mStrokeColor);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets clear on double click.
     *
     * @param clearOnDoubleClick the clear on double click
     */
    public void setClearOnDoubleClick(boolean clearOnDoubleClick) {
        mClearOnDoubleClick = clearOnDoubleClick;
    }

    /**
     * Gets pointer res.
     *
     * @return the pointer res
     */
    public int getPointerRes() {
        return mPointerRes;
    }

    /**
     * Sets pointer res.
     *
     * @param mPointerRes the m pointer res
     */
    public void setPointerRes(int mPointerRes) {
        this.mPointerRes = mPointerRes;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inMutable = true;
        this.mPointerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mPointerRes, options);
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Gets pointer bitmap.
     *
     * @return the pointer bitmap
     */
    public Bitmap getPointerBitmap() {
        return mPointerBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Sets pointer bitmap.
     *
     * @param mPointerBitmap the m pointer bitmap
     */
    public void setPointerBitmap(Bitmap mPointerBitmap) {
        this.mPointerBitmap = mPointerBitmap;
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Gets on draw listener.
     *
     * @return the on draw listener
     */
    public OnDrawListener getOnDrawListener() {
        return mOnDrawListener;
    }

    /**
     * Sets on draw listener.
     *
     * @param mOnDrawListener the m on draw listener
     */
    public void setOnDrawListener(OnDrawListener mOnDrawListener) {
        this.mOnDrawListener = mOnDrawListener;
    }

    /**
     * Gets overlay bitmap.
     *
     * @return the overlay bitmap
     */
    public Bitmap getOverlayBitmap() {
        return mOverlayBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Sets overlay bitmap.
     *
     * @param mOverlayBitmap the m overlay bitmap
     */
    public void setOverlayBitmap(Bitmap mOverlayBitmap) {
        this.mOverlayBitmap = mOverlayBitmap;
        invalidate();
    }
    //endregion

    /**
     * Start animation.
     */
    public void startAnimation() {
        animation(mExtractedPoints);
    }

    Random random = new Random();

    private void fade() {
        final short steps = 150;
        final byte stepDistance = 5;
        final byte maxTrailRadius = 15;
        mPathMeasure.setPath(mPath, false);
        final float pathLength = mPathMeasure.getLength();
        for (short i = 1; i <= steps; i++) {
            final float distance = pathLength - i * stepDistance;
            if (distance >= 0) {
                final float trailRadius = maxTrailRadius * (1 - (float) i / steps);
                mPathMeasure.getPosTan(distance, mPoint.getPoints(), null);
                final float x = mPoint.getPoints()[0] + random.nextFloat( ) - trailRadius;
                final float y = mPoint.getPoints()[1] +  random.nextFloat( ) - trailRadius;
                mPaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(
                        x,
                        y,
                        trailRadius > 0 ? trailRadius : Float.MIN_VALUE,
                        ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(mPaint.getColor(), random.nextInt(0xff)),
                        Color.TRANSPARENT,
                        Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
                ));
                mDrawingBitmapCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, trailRadius, mPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    private Paint getPaint() {
        mPaint.setShader(null);
        if (mMode == Mode.MARKER) {
            mPaint.setXfermode(null);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
        } else {
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.XOR));
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidthForEraser);
        }
        return mPaint;
    }

    /**
     * Clear the canvas.
     */
    public void clear() {
        if (mPoints != null) {
            mPoints.clear();
        }
        if (mExtractedPoints != null)
            mExtractedPoints.clear();

        if (mDrawingBitmap != null) {
            mDrawingBitmap = null;
            ensureDrawingBitmap();
        }
        if (null != mOnDrawListener) {
            mOnDrawListener.onClearCanvas(this);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Gets mode.
     *
     * @return the mode
     */
    public Mode getMode() {
        return mMode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets mode.
     *
     * @param mMode the m mode
     */
    public void setMode(Mode mMode) {
        this.mMode = mMode;
    }

    private TimePoint getNewPoint(TimePoint timePoint) {
        int mCacheSize = mPointsCache.size();
        TimePoint temp;
        if (mCacheSize == 0) {
            // Cache is empty, create a new point
            temp = new TimePoint();
        } else {
            // Get point from cache
            temp = mPointsCache.remove(mCacheSize - 1);
        }

        return temp.set(timePoint);
    }


    /**
     * Called when replaying history to ensure the dirty region includes all
     * mPoints.
     *
     * @param historicalX the previous x coordinate.
     * @param historicalY the previous y coordinate.
     */
    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < mDirtyRect.left) {
            mDirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > mDirtyRect.right) {
            mDirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }
        if (historicalY < mDirtyRect.top) {
            mDirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > mDirtyRect.bottom) {
            mDirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    private void recyclePoint(TimePoint point) {
        mPointsCache.add(point);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396584/how-tro-draw-fading-path) to another StackOverflow answer that pretty much should give you all of the information you need to reproduce the effect yourself.

Comment: It is not working. I tried hard to understand that code

Comment: I can't help you because I don't have your code to view. Also, what does "it is not working" mean? Is it doing something but just not what you wanted or is it doing nothing or is it crashing?

Comment: Because the code is incomplete and I am unaware of the idea, I implemented some rubbish things and it is not working for me.

Comment: The code is incomplete because StackOverflow answers aren't supposed to solve your problem but rather guide you to the solution. So for all intents and purpose consider the code at the link psuedocode meant to help you achieve your desired goal. You can ask the poster for the missing sections of code or even explain in further details the parts you are unsure of. Again, what isn't working exactly? Does the app run and not show the trailing effect or does it not compile?

Comment: Hi, I edited with the code sample. Inside there is a method called fade() that will do fade effect

Comment: And it is not fading and slow down my process

Comment: @Godwin Looking at your code, I don't see anywhere when you call fade() or when you instantiate mDrawingBitmapCanvas. Furthermore, I assume the idea behind the code is to draw the circles on the bitmap you receive in draw(Canvas). As for your slow down, I assume it's because you are doing a lot of work inside of your onTouchEvent(). Seems like a lot of object creation and I am unsure of what the methods calculateCurveControlPoints,  mBezierCached.set, and addBezier do but that is where I'd start.

Comment: I'd recommend just asking the original poster if he can give you assistance because he would know more than I would at this point. I am unsure of when he is setting his path object and when he clears it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161743/discussion-between-godwin-and-wade-wilson).